# Google Pie Chart Using Array

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I have tried to implement the following code using an array of two sets of values but the line graph does not show:

```
function drawChart() {

var lineTotalDistance = <?php echo json_encode($DistanceTotalArray) ?>;
var lineSpeed = <?php echo json_encode($SpeedArray) ?>;

//alert(lineTotalDistance.length);
//alert(lineSpeed.length);

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'Total Distance');
data.addColumn('number', 'Speed KM/H');

for(var i=0;i < lineTotalDistance.length; i++) {
        data.addRows([
        [lineTotalDistance, lineSpeed ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show a sample array that you're using and are you getting any errors in the browser's console ?

Comment: SpeedArray = 30, 79, 90 etc (3 values)
DistanceArray =  60, 60.1, 63.5 etc (3 values)

Comment: I meant what is the value of `$DistanceTotalArray` and `$SpeedArray`

Comment: It is a set of numbers with commas in between with a length of 386 each, also, whenever I alert the following under the for statement: alert((lineTotalDistance[i]), (lineSpeed[i])); <--what this does is it alerts only the distance and NOT Distance comma Speed so instead of getting 60, 300 it will return only 60 followed by the value of distance after 60 and so on..

Comment: Please post more code, it really is difficult to help you out without it.
Take a look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176285/pie-chart-using-mysql-and-php/32178442#32178442, see if it helps you in anyway.

Comment: on a side note, why don't you use the [arrayToDataTable()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#arraytodatatable) method?

Comment: @Criesto I had a look at your link to your answer, turns out I was missing JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK? not sure what that is.

Comment: @Criesto I did a bit of reading up, according to json_encode() constants, it would seem that my numbers were strings and not integers. Thank you!

Comment: @user5174952 if you check your json, you'll see that the integers are inside quotes which causes issues when you plot graph using it. `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` removes that quote from integer. If that answer has helped you please upvote, this will help someone having the same problem. Cheers!! :)

Comment: @Criesto I upvoted on your comment and answer from your link, thanks again for the explanation